# How to monitor audio on iPhone headphones from AVCaptureSession?

Tags: objective-c, avfoundation, core-audio, avcapturesession, cmsamplebufferref

I want to be able to monitor audio on headphones before and during the capture of video.

I have an `AVCaptureSession` set up to capture video and audio.

My idea is to hook and `AVCaptureAudioDataOutput` instance up to the `AVCaptureSession` for this and process the `CMSampleBufferRefs` with a class implementing the `AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate` protocol.

But I am not sure how to route the audio to the headphones from there.

What would be the most straighforward way to do this (highest level frameworks, general approach)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up implementing this `Audio Unit`. The remote i/o audio unit to be precise.
Apple's [aurioTouch sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/aurioTouch/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007770-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) provides a clear example of how to do this.